# Index error when using a while loop to iterate in a nested list

Tags: python, list, while-loop, index-error

When i run the below function i'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
def check_new(list1, val): 
    x= 0
    while x in range(len(list1)):
        x=x+1
        if list1[x][0]<=val<=list1[x][0]+4 or list1[x][1]-4<=val<=list1[x][1]:
            return 'Fail'
    return 'Pass'

list1 = [[97,103],[103,202],[202,250],[297,303]]
list2 = [100,200,300,400]

result_final=[check_new(list1, i) for i in list2]
```

This function returns output when i use a for loop instead of while loop

```
for x in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[x][0]<=val<=list1[x][0]+4 or list1[x][1]-4<=val<=list1[x][1]:
            return 'Fail'
    return 'Pass
```

Expected Output=

```
[Fail, Fail, Fail, Pass]
```

The reason i switched to while loop from for loop because my actual data has many rows and for loop is taking too long to run.

Comment: Placing `x = x + 1` after the if statement will have the same effect.

Comment: In fact, in Python, such a for loop is faster than a while loop.

Comment: Thanks! my actual data has 1M rows and it is taking forever to output. any ideas how to make this logic run faster? @MechanicPig

Comment: You can try multiprocessing

Comment: @propotato Notice that your data is ordered. Consider using a method similar to binary search instead of linear traversal.

Comment: @propotato can you elaborate problem , what you want to achieve, to make it faster ?
It seems that for every item in list2 you are checking whether that element lie in the ranges given in 1st list. If thats the case then definitely there is better solution.

Comment: @SandeepRawat. i'm checking if any item in list2 falls within a certain range of an item in list1 and label that as a fail. for ex if  any item of `list2` is within `97<x<97+4` or `103-4<x<103`, then that is a fail, if  any item of `list2` is within `103<x<103+4` or `202-4<x<202`, then that is a `Fail` and so on..

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check_new(list1, val): 
    x= 0
    while x in range(len(list1)):
        # removed x=x+1 from here, moved to end of while loop
        if list1[x][0]<=val<=list1[x][0]+4 or list1[x][1]-4<=val<=list1[x][1]:
            return 'Fail'
        x=x+1
    return 'Pass'
```

credits: @John Gordon